Jest Issue in angular, jest failed when execute 'jest xxxx'. TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
Error Message
below are the details:
node 18.x.x
angular 16.x.x
jest 29.x.x
......

here is the jest.config.js
modules.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  collectCoverage: true,
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@module/a': '<rootDir>/.../index.ts',
    '@module/b': '<rootDir>/.../index.ts',
    '@module/c': '<rootDir>/.../index.ts',
    ......
  }
}

a, b, c under @modules/ are libries configured in angular.json in application.
and there is a class in @module/c which extends an class declared in @module/a. But when I run the test file, the console told the above error in the picture. Have no idea about it. Seems like a dependency issue.
what should I do to fix this issue which most likely is a dependency issue
